# Entity Framework (EF6) delete bug

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I seem to have stumbled into an EF6 bug in deleting records with foreign key relationships. I have a parent table with 3 one to many tables, and 2 one to one tables. In an effort to delete the parent record, by deleting all of the children first, the generated SQL skips the one to one tables. Here's an example and the generated SQL:

```
/* select the parent records we want to remove */
var parentTable = Database.EampleTable.Where(x => x.Id == header.Id).ToList();

/* select the data records we are going to remove */
var oneToMany1 = parentTable.SelectMany(x => x.OneToMany1);
var oneToMany2 = parentTable.SelectMany(x => x.OneToMany2);
var oneToMany3 = parentTable.SelectMany(x => x.OneToMany3);
var oneToOne1 = parentTable.Select(x => x.OneToOne1).First();
var oneToOne2 = parentTable.Select(x => x.OneToOne2).First();

/* Remove the one-to-many related records */
Database.OneToMany1.RemoveRange(oneToMany1);
Database.OneToMany2.RemoveRange(oneToMany2);
Database.OneToMany3.RemoveRange(oneToMany3);

/* Remove the one-to-one related records */
Database.OneToOne1.Remove(oneToOne1);
Database.OneToOne2.Remove(oneToOne2);

Database.ExampleTable.RemoveRange(table);

await Database.SaveChangesAsync(); /* exception: foreign key constraint violation */
```

The generated SQL:

```
-- Generated SQL by Entity Framework, upon delete
exec sp_executesql N'DELETE [dbo].[OneToMany1]
WHERE (([Id] = @0) AND ([OneToMany1Id] = @1))',N'@0 int,@1 int',@0=1,@1=1
go
exec sp_executesql N'DELETE [dbo].[OneToMany2]
WHERE (([Id] = @0) AND ([OneToMany2Id] = @1))',N'@0 int,@1 int',@0=1,@1=3
go
exec sp_executesql N'DELETE [dbo].[OneToMany3]
WHERE (([Id] = @0) AND ([OneToMany3Id] = @1))',N'@0 int,@1 int',@0=1,@1=11
go
exec sp_executesql N'DELETE [dbo].[ExampleTable]
WHERE ([Id] = @0)',N'@0 int',@0=1
go
```

As you can see, the two OneToOne table records aren't deleted, therefore the attempt to delete the parent table throws an exception. As an *interesting side note*, if I comment out the delete statement for the parent table in the code, the generated SQL is still the same and it is trying to delete the parent table!

I've poured over the model files and context looking for errors (and so have others) and there simply aren't any. Right now my only solution is to write all the queries manually, but I'd love to know if anyone else has come across this with EF6.

Comment: Your side note is probably the key to figuring out the problem.  It sounds like, for a reason you'll have to determine, the code that you are showing us is not the code that is actually getting executed.

Comment: @sstan - the code is being run in the debugger as I step through it, and I'm monitoring the generated SQL using SQL Profiler in real-time. There are no outside method calls, but I am currently investigating the context management to see if something funny is going on outside of EF (unlikely, but I'm out of ideas)

Comment: nope, I created the context manually outside of the management system and got the same exact result.

Comment: Do you know that if a foreign key on the dependent entity is not nullable, then Code First sets cascade delete on the relationship? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#CascadeDelete

Comment: What Colins says is right. So it could be that EF is told (in the mappings) that the associations have cascaded delete and relies on that, but in reality, in the database, the foreign keys don't have cascaded delete.